# Cannot import name site with Haystack 2.0

Tags: django, django-haystack

I just updated to Haystack Version 2 and am getting the ImportError when trying to do a search that was previously working with 1.7.2.

`cannot import name site`

Traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/nutmegstore/apps/haystack/views.py" in __call__
  45.         self.form = self.build_form()
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/nutmegstore/apps/haystack/views.py" in build_form
  72.         return self.form_class(data, **kwargs)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/nutmegstore/apps/haystack/forms.py" in __init__
  90.         self.fields['models'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=model_choices(), required=False, label=_('Search In'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/nutmegstore/apps/haystack/forms.py" in model_choices
  12.     choices = [("%s.%s" % (m._meta.app_label, m._meta.module_name), capfirst(smart_unicode(m._meta.verbose_name_plural))) for m in connections[using].get_unified_index().get_indexed_models()]
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/nutmegstore/apps/haystack/utils/loading.py" in get_indexed_models
  268.             self.build()
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/nutmegstore/apps/haystack/utils/loading.py" in build
  197.             indexes = self.collect_indexes()
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/nutmegstore/apps/haystack/utils/loading.py" in collect_indexes
  166.                 search_index_module = importlib.import_module("%s.search_indexes" % app)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/nutmegstore/nutmegmodels/search_indexes.py" in <module>
  3. from haystack import site

Exception Type: ImportError at /search/
Exception Value: cannot import name site
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is because in the 2.0 release of Haystack haystack.site is removed.
The Haystack API has undergone some major changes in this new version and is still not in stable release. Using 1.2.7 is still the featured version for Django and documentbased searchengines.

You can read the [entire documentation here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migration_from_1_to_2.html) on how migrate for 1.x versions to 2.x

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Haha, well this is embarrassing. Thanks.